# PostgreSQL Docker installation how to setup initial database

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos

I am pretty new to the docker technology and working on setting up the docker container with PostgreSQL setup, up and running as a service and default database created with initial schema created with the .sql file.

The docker file i am using is as below -

```
FROM centos:centos6

# Upgrading system
#RUN yum -y upgrade
RUN yum -y install wget

#Installing POSTGRESQL
RUN rm /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

COPY CentOS-Base.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
COPY startup.sh /root/

RUN cd ~
RUN (curl -O http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm && \
rpm -ivh pgdg* && \
yum list postgres* && \
yum install -y  postgresql93-server && \
service postgresql-9.3 initdb)
echo "sh /root/startup.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
EXPOSE 5432
```

Few things which are very much required are - docker should be on Centos OS and PostgreSQL 9.3.

I am running the below startup script (startup.sh file) for post installation activities -

```
service postgresql-9.3 start
su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password 'xxxxxxx';\""
```

Now when i run the docker, it does installs and start the docker but throws the below error while trying to run the **alter user postgres with password 'xxxxxxx'** command.

Any suggestions how i can run the "psql" commands like the alter password above or may be something like loading schema from .sql file post installation automatically in docker container.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: there is an existing docker image for postgres. I would recommend to start from that image, otherwise you will have a lot of unused stuff inside your image. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: Where's the error? I'd also recommend not using the service commands since they expect a background/daemon application that will not work well with Docker. You should replace those that run the application in the foreground.

Comment: You appear to be treating the container as a lightweight VM, placing lots of state inside of the image, like setting the password in a bash startup script. The Docker design is much better focused on stateless images that run a single process with data and configurations stored in a volume.